# Node.js - How do you call an async function with a callback?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, callback

The async function below is supposed to check if a url is a legit url

```
let CheckUrl = function (url, done) {
  dns.lookup(url, function(err, address) { 
    if (err) return done(err);
    done(null, true); //return true because I don't care what the address is, only that it works
  });
}
```

The express.js code below gets the url but I'm having trouble understanding how to write the if statement so that it returns true or false.

```
// Gets URL 
app.post("/api/shorturl/new", function(req, res) {
  if (CheckUrl(req.body.url)) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

I'm not sure what to pass as the second argument in CheckUrl() in this if statement. Or maybe I wrote the first async function incorrectly to begin with?

Comment: Better to use async await

Comment: I have submitted an answer with the tested code below. Please approve the answer if it resolves your problem. 
Please check and let me know if you are getting any issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)  [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

I have written a test code for you as below:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const dns = require('dns');


let CheckUrl = function (url, done) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dns.lookup(url, function(err, address) {
            console.log("err " , err)
            if (err) {
                resolve(false)
            } else {
                resolve(true)
            }

        });
    });
} 


app.post("/api/shorturl/new", async function(req, res) {

  try {

    let result = await CheckUrl(req.body.url);
    console.log("result " , result)
    res.send(result)
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log("in catch error " , error)
    res.send(error)
  }
});

app.listen(3000)
```

you can get the knowledge to know about the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). The Promise object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation and its resulting value.

Comment: Thanks. Would I still need the done parameter in the checkurl function then?

Comment: This will not work. CheckUrl needs to return a promise. You **must** wrap `dns.lookup()` in a promise

Comment: @slebetman I have updated answer .. thanks for the information. :)

Comment: Thanks. When learning mongoose functions in freecodecamp, they taught to keep writing 'done' or 'callback' as the last parameter of the function. In this case, it looks like it's not even used. Can you clarify why that's needed or if that's even needed? I feel like there are two promises now - one is the 'done' parameter which is a callback in mongoose and the other is the new Promise() you wrote...

Comment: Ok, regarding the async await you can check the links which I have mentioned in the answer. and about the Promise, I have mentioned the link in the above answer. I don't know why they were using done. But here I know I am making synchronous code flow using Promise. I appreciate if you upvote and accept my answer If that helps you.

Comment: Thanks. Yes you're right. I found out that there's been many updates. v1 was using callback functions. v2 is using promises and .then(). v3 and the current year 2020 best practice is async/await as you wrote above. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by DeepKakkar, this was what I was looking for:

```
app.post("/api/shorturl/new", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let result = await CheckUrl(req.body.url);
    res.send(result)
  }
  catch (error) {
    return new Error('Could not receive post');
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert nodejs functions with callback into async functions this way:

```
function asyncNode(fn){
    return async function (...params){
        var res, rej;
        var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            res = resolve;
            rej = reject;
        });
        var cb = function (err, ...params){
            if (err)
                rej(err);
            else
                res(...params);
        };
        fn(...params, cb);
        return p;
    }
}


var echo = function (x, cb){
    setTimeout(function(){
        cb(null, x);
    }, 100);
};

var asyncEcho = asyncNode(echo);

(async function (){
    console.log(await asyncEcho(1));
    console.log(await asyncEcho(2));
    console.log(await asyncEcho(3));
    console.log(await asyncEcho(4));
})();
```